# Rectangular prism parametric equation

Tags: scene-graph

I have some problem in OSG doing my model, which need an rectangular prism, that I do not know the parametric equation.

I tried to search with the google, but no usable result.

Also tried to draw it by using this site: http://www.math.uri.edu/~bkaskosz/flashmo/tools/parsur/

Could somebody help to find the parametric equation for (x,y,z) cordinates

Comment: There are several different meanings for "OSG". Please could you specify which one this question refers to?

Comment: I dont think there is a good equation for a prism as such.

Answer (score 1):

A [prism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prism_%28geometry%29) is a polyhedron with a polygonal base, another parallel base of the same shape, and joining faces between corresponding edges of the two base faces.

The word "prism" is commonly used to describe a right prism with base faces perpendicular to the joining faces. In this case the joining faces are also rectangles, and so a rectangular right prism is simply a [cuboid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboid).

A cuboid can be described directly, but a simple way to generate one is to start with a cube and use directional [scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaling_%28geometry%29) to give the edges the required lengths.

If the base faces are not perpendicular to the joining faces, this oblique prism can be achieved by applying a [shear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping) to a cuboid with the required edge lengths.

So all you need is a parametric description of a cube, and you can go from there to any rectangular prism required.

---

As joojaa points out, there isn't an easy way to describe a prism (including a cube) in just a single parametrisation. You will need to describe each face with a separate set of parametric equations. For example, using parameters u and v, you could describe one of the faces as follows.

$$  x=u  \\  y=v  \\  z=1  \\  0 \leq u \leq 1  \\  0 \leq v \leq 1  $$

Comment: Thank you for your help, successfully created the prism. :)

I think, set the 8 points manually and draw with triangles is easier solution in this case. I believed it could be solved with a similar parametric equation, like cylinder.

Like you said, first create a cube, and scale it to the proper size solved the problem.